# Fetch module returns "unable to calculate the checksum of the remote file" while running in Docker but works fine when not in Docker

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-2.x

**Ansible playbook** (copy_file.yml):

```
- name: Copy this file over please
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Get files from scanners running in each DC
      fetch:
        src: /tmp/file_to_copy
        dest: /tmp/local_place
        flat: yes
        fail_on_missing: yes
        validate_checksum: no
```

**Command**: `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook/copy_file.yml`

It works when I run it.

But when I dockerize it, it gives me the **error**:

```
fatal: [remotehost.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "file": "/tmp/file_to_copy", "msg": "unable to calculate the checksum of the remote file"}
```

My dockerfile is very simple. It just copies a script that contains the ansible command and runs it. Its base image is `Alpine Linux`.
**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM some_url/alpine/python:3.7-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev
RUN apk add build-base
RUN apk add bash

COPY / /

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

Ansible version: ansible 2.9.2

Comment: Which version of ansible are you using ?

Comment: @Zeitounator ansible 2.9.2. Updated question.

Answer (score 3):

> Q: *"fatal: ... {"file": "/tmp/file_to_copy", "msg": "unable to calculate the checksum of the remote file"}

A: Try to find out why [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html#stat-retrieve-file-or-file-system-status) returns `checksum: 0`. For example

```
- hosts: remotehost.com
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: /tmp/file_to_copy
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stat.checksum
```

---

Notes

- See [Unable to calculate the checksum of the remote file. Shell is bash. ansible ver 2.0.2.0 #29769](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29769)
- The error is reported when the checksum is 0. See [lib/ansible/plugins/action/fetch.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/fetch.py)

```
if remote_checksum == '0':
    result['msg'] = "unable to calculate the checksum of the remote file"
```

- See [lib/ansible/plugins/action/**init**.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py)

```
def _remote_checksum(self, path, all_vars, follow=False):
    ...
    x = "0"  # unknown error has occurred
    try:
        remote_stat = self._execute_remote_stat(path, all_vars, follow=follow)
        ...
            x = remote_stat['checksum']  # if 1, file is missing
        ...
        return x  # pylint: disable=lost-exception
```

```
def _execute_remote_stat(self, path, all_vars, follow, tmp=None, checksum=True):
...
    mystat = self._execute_module(module_name='stat', module_args=module_args, task_vars=a
ll_vars, wrap_async=False)
    ...
    return mystat['stat']
```

Comment: Thank you. The `stat` module returned: `"Failed to connect to the host via ssh: root@remotehost.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).",`
It seems the Docker container does not contain the credentials to run SSH to the remote host.

Comment: The connection must be configured for this host with `ansible_connection: docker`

Comment: @Zeitounator `ansible_connection: docker` is used for Ansible connecting to other docker containers. In my case, it is a docker container talking to a remote host.