# Ansible unable to calculate the checksum error

Tags: ansible

Hoping with some help on the following. I'm trying to make reference to an xml file within the `work_dir` location:

```
---
- include_vars:
    file: var_file.yml

- name: Locate audit results file
  find:
    paths: "{{ item }}"
    recurse: no
    patterns: '*.xml'
  with_items: "{{ work_dir }}"
  register: audit_file

- name: Copy audit results file to local destination
  fetch:
    src: "{{ item }}/{{ audit_file }}"
    dest: /home/bob/audit_results/
    flat: yes
    validate_checksum: no
  with_items: "{{ work_dir }}"
```

var_file.yml:

```
---
work_dir:
  - /var/tmp/audit
```

However the above code keeps erroring with:

`"msg": "unable to calculate the checksum of the remote file"}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch module returns "unable to calculate the checksum of the remote file" while running in Docker but works fine when not in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59574516/fetch-module-returns-unable-to-calculate-the-checksum-of-the-remote-file-while)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε this is not a duplicate of the above. The problem here is that  the path does not exists since there is a wrong usage of the registered var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `find` files on a loop of paths and register the result. Therefore your registered var `audit_file` contains a [`results` attribute which is a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop).

Each element of the `results` list contains a [`files` attribute](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#return-files) which is again a list. Each `files` element contains a result of your find run with all the info about the found file. In those info, there is a `path` attribute pointing to the exact path of the file on the remote server.

Before going further, I strongly suggest your read the above documentation and issue a `debug` of your var to understand its structure and content

```
- debug:
    var: audit_file
```

If you want to fetch each found file, you need to make a loop on each `results` with a sub-loop on each `files` element. This can be done with a [`subelements` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html) although we will only use here the sub element (i.e. `item.1`) of the loop.

This is how you can fix your second task:

```
- name: Copy audit results file to local destination
  fetch:
    src: "{{ item.1.path }}"
    dest: /tmp/test/
    flat: yes
    validate_checksum: no
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ audit_file.results }}"
    - files
```

Note: this is not the only solution, I went to the easiest and most obvious.

Comment: I have some reading to do now! :)

Can I ask (not looking for solution here, more so some pointers), is it possible to pass in the ```dest``` as a var from ```var_file```, rather than the way I have it? If so, can you suggest some possible areas I should read up on that will help with this?

Comment: Of course, you can use a variable defined anywhere https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html